# how to redirect to a php file within an html select tag

Tags: php, html, forms, post, foreach

I am trying to make an inex.php file as a dashboard page that shows a selection of files that are part of the folder that index.php is part of. and when the user selects the file, I want it to redirect to that page. I am using xammp as a local webserver for this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Admin portal</h1>

    <h3>select a php file relevent to a table in the database you would like to manage :index brings you right back :(</h3>




    <form action="" method="POST">
        <label for="pages">page:</label>
        <select name="pages" id="page">
            <?php
            foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {

                echo "<option value='strtolower($filename)'>$filename</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">



    </form>



</body>

</html>
```

I am using a foreach to get all the files that are in the folder and populate them in a selection menu. I want to know how I can redirect to those files when I hit submit.

Comment: Create another page and base to select header to this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, you need only remove ***strtolower*** method from value, and use onchange on select tag.

Edit, Second Sol when **submitted form** :

```
 <form action="" method="POST"  onsubmit="return submitForm()">
            <label for="pages">page:</label>
            <select name="pages" id="page"  >
                <?php
                foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
                    $filename = strtolower($filename);
                    echo "<option value='$filename'>$filename</option>";
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit"  id='submitBtn'  value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitForm(){
                window.location.href =  document.getElementById("page").value;
                return false;
            }
    </script>
```

First sol,Try it:

```
<select name="pages" id="page" onchange=" (window.location = this.value);">
        <?php
        foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
            $filename = strtolower($filename);
            echo "<option value='$filename'>$filename</option>";
        }
        ?>
  </select>
```

Comment: how would i make it so that it does the redirect  only until I hit submit on a form

Comment: Okay, I'll Edit the solution now check it!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a select to redirect, use a `<a>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Admin portal</h1>

    <h3>select a php file relevent to a table in the database you would like to manage :index brings you right back :(</h3>


    <h1>pages</h1>
    <ul>
    <?php
        foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
            echo "<li><a href=" . strtolower($filename) . ">" . $filename . "</a></li>";
        }
    ?>
    </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

// edit: wrong concat operand

Comment: i get an error with this

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string + string in E:\lamp\htdocs\EHR\admin\index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\lamp\htdocs\EHR\admin\index.php on line 21

Comment: Oops, fixed that, confused with JS

Comment: Does it work now??